# How can I report the API of a class programmatically?

Tags: python, api

My goal is to parse a class and return a data-structure (object, dictionary, etc) that is descriptive of the methods and the related parameters contained within the class.  Bonus points for types and returns...

Requirements: Must be Python

For example, the below class:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(hello=None):
         return hello

    def baz(world=None):
         return baz
```

Would be parsed to return

```
result = {class:"Foo", 
          methods: [{name: "bar", params:["hello"]}, 
                    {name: "baz", params:["world"]}]}
```

So that's just an example of what I'm thinking... I'm really flexible on the data-structure.

Any ideas/examples on how to achieve this?

Comment: looks question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990016/how-to-find-out-the-arity-of-a-method-in-python, it contains what you will need and also explains what you can't do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to check out Python's [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) module. It will get you most of the way there:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def bar(hello=None):
...          return hello
...     def baz(world=None):
...          return baz
...
>>> import inspect
>>> members = inspect.getmembers(Foo)
>>> print members
[('__doc__', None), ('__module__', '__main__'), ('bar', <unbound method Foo.bar>
), ('baz', <unbound method Foo.baz>)]
>>> inspect.getargspec(members[2][1])
(['hello'], None, None, (None,))
>>> inspect.getargspec(members[3][1])
(['world'], None, None, (None,))
```

This isn't in the syntax you wanted, but that part should be fairly straight forward as you read the docs.

Comment: `inspect` looks just like what you're looking for. For a more low-tech solution, you can just take a look at `Foo.__dict__` which contains most (all?) of `class Foo`'s members.

Comment: ...and also `Foo.__name__` to get the name of the class. Useful when you're passed an object which contains a class.