# How to get the number of args of a built-in function in Python?

Tags: python

I need to programmatically get the number of arguments that a function requires. With functions declared in modules this is trivial:

```
myfunc.func_code.co_argcount
```

But built-in functions don't have the `func_code` attribute. Is there another way to do this? Otherwise I can't use the built-ins and have to re-write them in my code.

[addition] Thanks for the responses, hope they'll be useful. I have used Pypy instead.

Comment: I posted another approach here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567935/get-parameter-count-of-builtin-functions-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the function below copied from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/553262-list-classes-methods-and-functions-in-a-module/).  This may be the best you can do.  Note the comments about `inspect.getargspec`.

```
def describe_builtin(obj):
   """ Describe a builtin function """

   wi('+Built-in Function: %s' % obj.__name__)
   # Built-in functions cannot be inspected by
   # inspect.getargspec. We have to try and parse
   # the __doc__ attribute of the function.
   docstr = obj.__doc__
   args = ''

   if docstr:
      items = docstr.split('\n')
      if items:
         func_descr = items[0]
         s = func_descr.replace(obj.__name__,'')
         idx1 = s.find('(')
         idx2 = s.find(')',idx1)
         if idx1 != -1 and idx2 != -1 and (idx2>idx1+1):
            args = s[idx1+1:idx2]
            wi('\t-Method Arguments:', args)

   if args=='':
      wi('\t-Method Arguments: None')

   print
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this type of introspection is possible with built-in functions, or any C extension function for that matter.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990016/how-to-find-out-the-arity-of-a-method-in-python) was already asked here, and Alex's answer suggests parsing the docstring of the function to determine the number of args.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a more robust alternative to the parsing function given by Alex, but this will still fail to give appropriate arg specs because, not all docstrings fully represent their function's signature.

A good example being `dict.get` where the args spec should be `(k, d=None)`, but the function I've defined will return `(k, d)`, because no default is given for `d` in the form `d=None`. In the docstring `"f(a[, b, c])"` the args `b` and `c` are defaults, but there's no real way to parse them because no value is directly specified and, in the case of `dict.get`, the behavior is described later on, not in the signature representation.

On the bright side though, this captures all the arguments, it's just that defaults aren't reliable.

```
import re
import inspect

def describe_function(function):
    """Return a function's argspec using its docstring

    If usages discovered in the docstring conflict, or default
    values could not be resolved, a generic argspec of *arg
    and **kwargs is returned instead."""
    s = function.__doc__
    if s is not None:
        usages = []
        p = r'([\w\d]*[^\(])\( ?([^\)]*)'
        for func, usage in re.findall(p, s):
            if func == function.__name__:
                usages.append(usage)

        longest = max(usages, key=lambda s: len(s))
        usages.remove(longest)

        for u in usages:
            if u not in longest:
                # the given usages weren't subsets of a larger usage.
                return inspect.ArgSpec([], 'args', 'kwargs', None)
        else:
            args = []
            varargs = None
            keywords = None
            defaults = []

            matchedargs = re.findall(r'( ?[^\[,\]]*) ?,? ?', longest)
            for a in [a for a in matchedargs if len(a)!=0]:
                if '=' in a:
                    name, default = a.split('=')
                    args.append(name)
                    p = re.compile(r"<\w* '(.*)'>")
                    m = p.match(default)
                    try:
                        if m:
                            d = m.groups()[0]
                            # if the default is a class
                            default = import_item(d)
                        else:
                            defaults.append(eval(default))
                    except:
                        # couldn't resolve a default value
                        return inspect.ArgSpec([], 'args', 'kwargs', None)
                elif '**' in a:
                    keywords = a.replace('**', '')
                elif '*' in a:
                    varargs = a.replace('*', '')
                else:
                    args.append(a)
            return inspect.ArgSpec(args, varargs, keywords, defaults)

# taken from traitlet.utils.importstring
def import_item(name):
    """Import and return ``bar`` given the string ``foo.bar``.

    Calling ``bar = import_item("foo.bar")`` is the functional equivalent of
    executing the code ``from foo import bar``.

    Parameters
    ----------
    name : string
      The fully qualified name of the module/package being imported.

    Returns
    -------
    mod : module object
       The module that was imported.
    """
    if not isinstance(name, string_types):
        raise TypeError("import_item accepts strings, not '%s'." % type(name))
    name = cast_bytes_py2(name)
    parts = name.rsplit('.', 1)
    if len(parts) == 2:
        # called with 'foo.bar....'
        package, obj = parts
        module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
        try:
            pak = getattr(module, obj)
        except AttributeError:
            raise ImportError('No module named %s' % obj)
        return pak
    else:
        # called with un-dotted string
        return __import__(parts[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.  C functions do not expose their argument signatures programmatically.

Comment: It is possible. I posted a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567935/get-parameterarg-count-of-builtin-functions-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Interesting solution, ars. Hope it helps others too.

I went another way: I had heared that Pypy is python implemented mostly in itself. So I tried [PyPy](http://pypy.org/download.html) (JIT version) and it worked. I haven't found a "hard-coded" function yet. Couldn't find out how to install it in /usr, but it works from a folder where it's unpacked.