# Length of arguments of Python function?

Tags: python, function, parameters, arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out the arity of a method in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990016/how-to-find-out-the-arity-of-a-method-in-python)

For example I have declared a function:

```
def sum(a,b,c):
    return a + b + c
```

I want to get length of arguments of "sum" function.
somethig like this: some_function(sum) to returned 3

 How can it be done in Python?

**Update:**
I asked this question because I want to write a function that accepts another function as a parameter and  arguments to pass it.

```
def funct(anotherFunct, **args):
```

and I need to validate:

```
if(len(args) != anotherFuct.func_code.co_argcount):
    return "error"
```

Comment: You can see the source code, can't you? It's obviously 3.  What more do you need to know?

Comment: why don't you try passing `*args` and return `return len(args)` or `return len(filter(None, args))` !!!

Comment: because I want to write a function that accepts another function as a parameter and arguments to pass it. def funct(anotherFunct, **args): and I need to validate: if(len(args) != anotherFuct.func_code.co_argcount): return "error"

Comment: Please **update** your question to include all the background information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your method name is `sum` then `sum.func_code.co_argcount` will give you number of arguments.

Comment: What downsides are there in using this method? Given the other answers I assume using `inspect` is the preferred way. Why is this?

Answer (score 16):

The `inspect` module is your friend; specifically `inspect.getargspec` which gives you information about a function's arguments:

```
>>> def sum(a,b,c):
...     return a + b + c
...
>>> import inspect
>>> argspec = inspect.getargspec(sum)
>>> print len(argspec.args)
3
```

`argspec` also contains details of optional arguments and keyword arguments, which in your case you don't have, but it's worth knowing about:

```
>>> print argspec
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import inspect

print len(inspect.getargspec(sum)[0])
```