# Python function parameter count

Tags: python, metaprogramming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find out the arity of a method in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990016/how-to-find-out-the-arity-of-a-method-in-python)

Given a python function, how do I programmatically determine the number of parameters it takes?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/990016/how-to-find-out-the-arity-of-a-method-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913963/length-of-arguments-of-python-function/3915056#3915056

Answer (score 11, accepted):

inspect is your friend in this case

```
>>> def testFunc(arg1, arg2, arg3, additional='test'):
...     print arg1
... 
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getargspec(testFunc)
ArgSpec(args=['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3', 'additional'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=('test',))
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

From outside the function, you can use inspect.getargspec(): http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [inspect.getargspec(func)](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.6/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#inspect.getargspec) command. That gives you a tuple, the first element of which is a list of the required parameters.