# Use Boost-Python to Find Number of Arguments that Function Have

Tags: python, python-2.7, boost-python

I have a user-defined function in python which I don't know how many arguments it has. i.e. It can be

```
def f1(x,y,z):
  return  sin(x)*cos(y)*tan(z)
```

or

```
def f1(x):
  return  sin(x)
```

**How I can use Boost-Python to find how many arguments the function has?** If I just had 1 function argument, I could always evaluate like this:

```
  bp::object f1 = main_dict["f1"];
  std::cout << bp::extract<double>(f1(0.0)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Do you specifically need **Boost-Python**? If not, just use `*args` and find the length of that

Comment: I want to get access to the number of arguments of python function in C++. How I can use args to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For user-defined functions in python, it is possible to extract the [arity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of a function through the `func_code` special attribute.  This attribute represents the compiled function body, and provides a `co_argcount` attribute indicating the function's arity.  For more information and other possible approaches, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990016/how-to-find-out-the-arity-of-a-method-in-python) question.

Ignoring error checking, the Boost.Python implementation becomes fairly trivial:

```
boost::python::extract<std::size_t>(fn.attr("func_code").attr("co_argcount"));
```

---

Here is a complete brief example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

void print_arity(boost::python::object fn)
{
  std::size_t arity = boost::python::extract<std::size_t>(
                        fn.attr("func_code").attr("co_argcount"));
  std::cout << arity << std::endl;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  def("print_arity", &print_arity);
}
```

And its usage:

```
>>> from example import print_arity
>>> def f1(x,y,z): pass
... 
>>> print_arity(f1)
3
>>> def f1(x): pass
... 
>>> print_arity(f1)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def foobar(x, *args):
    return len(args) + 1
```

The `*args` in the parameter list assigns all extra arguments not explicitly defined in the paramater list to a list `args` (this name is user-defined). Assuming the function must have at least one parameter, the above function will return the number of arguments.

**Disclaimer:** I have no experience whatsoever with Boost.Python. This answer is merely the implementation in Python and transferring the return value into C++ is up to the user.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the question is about finding the arity of a function (i.e. how many arguments does `foobar` accept), and not the count of invocation arguments (i.e. `len(args) + 1`).