# Show arguments of a function

Tags: python

I want to see the arguments of a function in a specific library, example:

```
import lib
```

Let's say that lib contains a function `func` with two arguments: size and date.
I want to find a function `help` such that when I do something like `help(lib.func)`, it gives me something like `TWO ARGUMENTS: size and date`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out the arity of a method in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990016/how-to-find-out-the-arity-of-a-method-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`inspect.getfullargspec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfullargspec).

> Get the names and default values of a Python function’s parameters. A named tuple is returned:
>
> `FullArgSpec(args, varargs, varkw, defaults, kwonlyargs, kwonlydefaults, annotations)`